# Application doesn't work in iPad Simulator, fine in iPhone Simulator

Tags: ipad, sdk, ios-simulator

I created an application and it runs OK when I use the iPhone Simulator. When I try to run it on the iPad Simulator it doesn't work.

Several things that may assist anyone who tries to assist with this issue:

1. In the iPhone Simulator I tried to change the Hardware settings - selecting Device---iPad and also changing the Version (3.2 and 4.0). did not do any difference.
2. When it runs with the Device---iPad selection it simply opens it with iPhone Simulator
3. When I open the iPad Simulator without Build and Run from XCode I don't see my app in the applications list on the simulator view.

Should I define something in XCode or in the simulator (like saying "this application should also run in iPad")?

May the problem be related to versions issue? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The simulator will open to which ever device the project target is set to. Therefore, if you set it to iPhone it will always open in the iPhone simulator. Similarly if you set it to iPad it will only open in the iPad simulator. If you set it to be Universal, then it will support both.

It has nothing to do with which hardware type you select in the simulator. You have to change the target Devices.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the quick answer.
I'm sorry for the dumb question, but how exactly do I add/change a/the target?